# Jhipster : issue with Grunt on blank project

Tags: gruntjs, jhipster

I am trying to package a Jhipster 2.1.1 application.
I know it's not supported anymore, but I am maintaining this webapp and we are not able to upgrade Jhipster version.
As the packaging with Grunt doesn't work I have just created a blank application (in order to test Grunt) and ran:

```
mvn -Pprod package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I am getting : 
[

```
ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.2:build (run-grunt) on project jhipster: Error during : grunt test --no-color: Process exited with an error: 3 (Exit value: 3) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.2:build (run-grunt) on project jhipster: Error during : grunt test --no-color
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error during : grunt test --no-color
    at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.executeCommand(YeomanMojo.java:104)
    at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.logAndExecuteCommand(YeomanMojo.java:85)
    at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.grunt(YeomanMojo.java:73)
    at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.execute(YeomanMojo.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 3 (Exit value: 3)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:147)
    at com.github.trecloux.yeoman.YeomanMojo.executeCommand(YeomanMojo.java:102)
    ... 31 more
```

[UPDATE]

```
➜  grunt -V
grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v0.4.5
➜  bower -v
1.8.0
➜  node -v
v4.7.2
```

I found the pb, jasmine-core and requireJs were missing. Now packaging works fine. But when I deploy my war on Tomcat7, the image ('jhipster man') doesn't show. I am getting these errors in the browser :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Introuvable)
http://localhost:8181/jhipster/api/account?cacheBuster=1485698191924 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Non-Autorisé)
http://localhost:8181/assets/images/5483e159.hipster.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Introuvable)
http://localhost:8181/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Introuvable)
http://localhost:8181/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Introuvable)
http://localhost:8181/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Introuvable)
```

Comment: As it is a blank project, you could share it on github

Comment: you can look at my update

Comment: Well for your 404 errors, images when built with `mvn -Pprod` are versionned with a hash code: hipster.png -> 5483e159.hipster.png. If your build is fine you should find them in your war file (unzip it) so I suppose that you did not set the prod profile in Tomcat. Check in your logs, when the app starts up it prints the active spring profile. Using Tomcat is much more complex than executing the jar.

Comment: I did set profile to Prod. I think the problem is related to prod profile. The path doesn't seem to be right. It should be http://localhost:8181/jhipster/assets/...  but it is http://localhost:8181/assets/ I don't know why it is looking for the wrong path.

Comment: In the war file I have hipster.png in assets/images and 5483e159.hipster.png in dist/assets/images

Comment: So build is OK, now you must ensure prod profile is activated at runtime. This is purely a spring boot question now

Comment: When I run tomcat7, the log says that the active profile is Prod. ( Running with Spring profile(s) : prod) Is there another way to ensure that?

Comment: When I remove prod profile from JAVA_OPTS, it works, images and fonts are well loaded. But of course I am in DEV mode, not in PROD anymore

Comment: Does it work in PROD when you run the executable war? By the way, jhipster 2.2.1 is based on spring boot 1.2.0 which depends on tomcat 8, so using tomcat 7 is just looking for trouble

Comment: I am using Jhister 2.1.1   When I run the executable war, it seems to work fine. I don't understand why using Tomcat7 with prod profile does'nt.